# How to improve jQuery performance with appending icons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am building a spreadsheet editor with jQuery and I am encountering performance issues with big tables. 
The table holds many data sets and when clicked on one, icons are added to the first cell of the other sets. The code looks like this:

```
$('.click_icon').remove();
for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
  var first_cell = $('td.content[dataset="' + datasets[i].id + '"]').filter(':first');
  if (in_group(datasets[i].id)) {
    first_cell.append('<i class="icon-remove click_icon remove_group" style="float:right"></i>');
  } else {
    first_cell.append('<i class="icon-magnet click_icon add_group" style="float:right"></i>');
}
```

with 500+ datasets this takes about 5 seconds. `in_group()` is just a small function which checks if the set is in a group with the selected data set.

I was wondering if creating the icons prior to the click and using `show() hide()` would be faster? Any other ideas?

I am using Chromium on Ubuntu. (Version 28.0.1500.52 Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the table in memory and only change the DOM once :

```
$('.click_icon').remove();
var table = $('table');
var clone = table.clone(true);

for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
  var _class = in_group(datasets[i].id) ? 
                     'icon-remove click_icon remove_group' : 
                     'icon-magnet click_icon add_group',
      elem   = $('<i />', {'class': _class, style:'float:right'});

  $('td.content[dataset="' + datasets[i].id + '"]', clone).filter(':first')
                                                          .append(elem);
}

table.replaceWith(clone);
```

This is a general example, you may have to adjust this to make it work properly with your markup.
I'd normally use plain JS for performance, and documentFragments, but I think jQuery uses fragments internally when doing it this way.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I am a little confused with the syntax!? shouldn't there be a semicolon after the definition of _class?

Comment: hmm, too bad. with this approach it takes even longer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, appending element by string is worst for performance than creating element by DOM.

So try anything like this:

```
if (in_group(datasets[i].id)) {
   var i = document.createElement('i');
   i.className = 'icon-remove click_icon remove_group';
   i.style.float = 'right';
   first_cell.appendChild(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the users to click, I think creating the icons prior to the click is a good idea.

Instead of show/hide which toggles the display property, you could use the [visibility property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility). When the visibility changes from hidden to visible, the browser doesn't need to recalculate the layout.

Comment: with `.css('visibility', 'visible');`?

Comment: Yes! Or you can toggle classes, visibility:hidden vs. visibility:visible